# Python - How to shorten code

Tags: python, function

I've developed a Python program that I need advice on simplifying.

This is part of my code:

```
import wx
import sys
import socket

def error_handler(c):
    if c == 'canceled':
        sys.exit('User canceled configuration.')
    elif c == 'empty':
        sys.exit('Empty value.')


def hostname():
    dlg = wx.TextEntryDialog(None,
                             'What is your default Hostname?',
                             'Hostname',
                             socket.gethostname())

    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_CANCEL:
        error_handler('canceled')
    else:
        if dlg.GetValue() == "":
            error_handler('empty')
        else:
            HOSTNAME = dlg.GetValue()
            return HOSTNAME


def random_hostname():
    dlg = wx.SingleChoiceDialog(None,
                                'Do you want to randomize your Hostname',
                                'Randomize',
                                ['Yes', 'No', 'Disable'],
                                wx.CHOICEDLG_STYLE)

    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_CANCEL:
        error_handler('canceled')
    else:
        RANDOM_HOSTNAME = dlg.GetStringSelection()
        return RANDOM_HOSTNAME


def nameserver():
    dlg = wx.TextEntryDialog(None,
                             'Nameserver IP\n',
                             'Nameserver',
                             '127.0.0.1')

    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_CANCEL:
        error_handler('canceled')
    else:
        if dlg.GetValue() == "":
            error_handler('empty')
        else:
            NAMESERVER = dlg.GetValue()
            return NAMESERVER


def main():
    app = wx.App()
    print 'HOSTNAME =', hostname()
    print 'RANDOM_HOSTNAME =', random_hostname()
    print 'NAMESERVER =', nameserver()
    app.MainLoop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In this code I make function for Hostname, Random hostname and nameserver, but in all 3 function I have to repeat almost same code:

```
if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_CANCEL:
    error_handler('canceled')
else:
    if dlg.GetValue() == "":
        error_handler('empty')
    else:
        HOSTNAME = dlg.GetValue()
        return HOSTNAME
```

But I want to make more than 20 functions for checking some values.
Is there (and I know that there is) some better trick to shorten every function?

I want something like this:

```
import wx
import sys
import socket

def error_handler(c):
    if c == 'canceled':
        sys.exit('User canceled configuration.')
    elif c == 'empty':
        sys.exit('Empty value.')
    else
        return dialog value


def hostname():
    dlg = wx.TextEntryDialog(None,
                             'What is your default Hostname?',
                             'Hostname',
                             socket.gethostname())

    error_handler(dlg)


def random_hostname():
    dlg = wx.SingleChoiceDialog(None,
                                'Do you want to randomize your Hostname',
                                'Randomize',
                                ['Yes', 'No', 'Disable'],
                                wx.CHOICEDLG_STYLE)

    error_handler(dlg)


def nameserver():
    dlg = wx.TextEntryDialog(None,
                             'Nameserver IP\n',
                             'Nameserver',
                             '127.0.0.1')

    error_handler(dlg)


def main():
    app = wx.App()
    print 'HOSTNAME =', hostname()
    print 'RANDOM_HOSTNAME =', random_hostname()
    print 'NAMESERVER =', nameserver()
    app.MainLoop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I wish to thank everybody who will help me with this.

Comment: This would probable work better at codeview.stackexchage: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. I suggest asking there.

Comment: oh. didn't know that I posted in wrong section. thx for sugestion

Answer (score 0):

It looks you already know the answer with creating another function, `error_handler` to do the repeated work! You could wrap your error handler in a [try/except](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) block that would look something along the lines of this:

```
def hostname():
    try:
        dlg = wx.TextEntryDialog(None,
                     'What is your default Hostname?',
                     'Hostname',
                      socket.gethostname())
    except:
        error_handler(dlg)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def funct(dlg, wx, funcCheck):
    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_CANCEL:
        error_handler('canceled')
    else:
        if dlg.GetValue() == "":
            error_handler('empty')
        else:
            value = funcCheck()
            return value
```

then you can call it this way

```
funct(dlg, wx, dlg.GetValue)
```

Continue to add conditions to the function depending on what you want